# Suggestions for Stress Testing BlazeDS

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, blazeds, stress-testing

We are removing our XSL-> HTML solution annd replacing it with a Flex UI for our userbase. One of the concerns is that the BlazeDS (amf endpoint, so streaming or polling) won't be able to handle the load as well as the EJB -> XML -> XSLT -> HTML stack. My theory is that it should perform better, but I need a way to statistically prove this.

Are there any suggestions for a product and/or method for stress-testing BlazeDS? Adobe has a stress test framework for LCDS, but it says it is not compatible with BlazeDS. I think that it might be simple to test given that I am not planning on using it as a messeging solution right now, and simple want it as an endpoint for RemoteObject connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at using JMeter to run some automated tests against the backend:

http://jmeter.apache.org/

You should be able to write a test against the backend which takes some Java objects and uses the API available in Blaze to encode them in AMF and set the result as the body of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Rob de Boer has a good article on implementing such an approach here http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/07/14/performance-testing-a-flex-blazeds-application/

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Cliff's answer, there is now a JMeter plugin for handling AMF messages. It will deserialize the message to XML so that it can be edited. You can use variables to generate unique session ids that are inserted into each AMF sample.

http://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf

Full disclosure: I am the project author.

Answer (score 0):

Several frameworks come to mind:

- [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)
- [perf4j](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/)
- [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/).

> , but I need a way to statistically prove this.

Hm, if you want really expressive statistics (e.g. besides average, max, min also standard deviation, or even 95% confidence interval or serial correlation), you'll have to take a close look at the tools, since most of them are weak on statistics.

Hopefully [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146207/what-is-the-best-macro-benchmarking-tool-framework-to-measure-a-single-threaded/7445378#7445378) explaining the strength and weakness of several performance testing tools can help you.

Answer (score 0):

My Company (UBIK-INGENIERIE) distributes a commercial Apache JMeter plugin to load test AMF based applications and by extension BlazeDS ones.

You can easily record, variabilize and replay Flex/AMF based application with standard knowledge of Apache JMeter.

See:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/-Solutions-
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubik-load-pack/