# Providing logging (debug) context

Tags: java, debugging, logging

I have an application that uses several different Java classes and would like to be able to supply debugging context to logging messages.

This (application and data-specific) context (basically, a string) will be constructed or retrieved somehow by each class individually and will be passed to the appropriate logging call, e.g.

```
logger.debug(context + ", whatever error message");
```

So, my question is, what would be the best pattern to use in order to implement this functionality across the application?

I am thinking of having all classes that need to support context-sensitive logging implement a Java interface with a few appropriate methods, e.g.

```
public interface ContextSensitive
{
    public String getContext();
    public String setContext();
}
```

where the **`setContext()`** method will be useful for cases where an object (say) secondObject is instantiated from an object (say) firstObject that has context, but secondObject has not. So, firstObject would also do something like

```
secondObject = new SecondObject();
secondObject.setContext(context);
```

Does the above make sense, or should I do something better?

An alternative I have been considering is to write a wrapper around the logging library to offer this functionality, but I don't see any value to this approach, compared to the one I described above, based on the `ContextSensitive` interface.

If there are any examples of open source projects that had to tackle the same issue, I would appreciate a link.

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but not all answers really work. :-)

Comment: If you found your own answer, then post it and accept it to provide feed back to the community or at least accept the answer that at least partially answer the question. If there is really no good answer, then probably you asked the wrong question :)

Comment: Ah, yes, I can post my own answer! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something similar to [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) (mapped diagnostic context) which is a feature of log4j, logback and slf4j frameworks. The context can be set only once before the method call and then logging framework can be configured to produce logging messages including fields from the context.

Comment: I have played with MDC, but the problem is that it works per thread and I need to change the context within the same thread, numerous times.

Comment: Use AOP (or Servlet Filter if you have a web app) to set your context. That's pretty standard aproach to this problem and it will kepp your code cleaner as you will not have to care about passing the context to all your methods all the time.

Comment: What is your archicture/frameworks/application server? Answer will depend on that.

Comment: Just plain vanilla Java. For debugging I use Log4j/Log5j.

Comment: Actually I had a closer look at AOP and it is not what I would like to do at this point. I am interested in a "plain" Java solution (as opposed to using things like AspectJ).

Comment: "plain" Java sounds like you don't use any of dependecy injection frameworks, right?

Comment: Exactly. No Spring or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of a [cross-cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), so use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: Actually I had a closer look at AOP and it is not what I would like to do at this point. I am interested in a "plain" Java solution (as opposed to using things like AspectJ).

Comment: If you would give a concrete example of the information you want to log, maybe someone will suggest a library. I did so for performance analysis below, but that doesn't seem to be your situation....

Comment: It is just a few String values that need to be passed across objects, but may change numerous times within the same thread (data-specific). Sort of session management.

Answer (score 1):

What is the information used for that you want to log?

If it's for performance analysis, take a look at [What is the best macro-benchmarking tool / framework to measure a single-threaded complex algorithm in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146207/what-is-the-best-macro-benchmarking-tool-framework-to-measure-a-single-threaded/7445378#7445378), there are some tools listed that use logging mechanisms.