# What is O(n) for java.util.Random.next(n)

Tags: java, time-complexity

I want to know whether `java.util.Random.next(n)` scales linearly with n or is a constant? Could someone help me with this or show me how to go about determining the complexity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the docs:

> Random.nextInt(n) uses Random.next() less than twice on average- it
>   uses it once, and if the value obtained is above the highest multiple
>   of n below MAX_INT it tries again, otherwise is returns the value
>   modulo n (this prevents the values above the highest multiple of n
>   below MAX_INT skewing the distribution), so returning a value which is
>   uniformly distributed in the range 0 to n-1.

According to the docs the `java.util.Random.next` is implemented as follows

```
synchronized protected int next(int bits) {
   seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
   return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));
 }
```

So the complexity is O(1)

**On a side note:-**

You can use several tools which are there to measure the complexity with a micro-benchmark. You can find a list over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146207/what-is-the-best-macro-benchmarking-tool-framework-to-measure-a-single-threade). However if the runtime complexity is important to you you can use the [Fast Mersenne Twister](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/).(This is an external library to measure the runtime complexity as Javas random number generators are quite fast, but statistically bad)

Answer (score 9):

The Javadoc of `next` explains

> The method `next` is implemented by class Random by atomically updating the seed to
>
> `(seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)`
>
> and returning
>
> `(int)(seed >>> (48 - bits))`

Clearly, there is no trace of O(n) complexity in these expressions.

Comment: I accepted the first answer because it seemed to be correct. Yours is roughly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Runtime is `O(1)` if [this source code example](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html) is still relevant.

```
 173:   protected synchronized int next(int bits)
 174:   {
 175:     seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
 176:     return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
 177:   }
```

I would believe it is due to Oracle's explaination on how they generate random numbers [in this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of pseudorandom
>   numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a
>   linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer
>   Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.2.1.)

Comment: sorry about that, I totally misread the question. deleteting the comment now